# No write access to partition shared with Windows

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, windows, dual-boot

I dual boot Windows and Linux. On one drive I have Linux and on the other I split it in to two partitions, one for Windows and another for games.

I intend to use Windows just to play games, since Linux does not support the games I like to play. I want to have the partition for games be shared between the two systems.

I can mount the partition no problem but when I want to delete or create files I don't have permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the MS-Windows does not shutdown when asked to, it hibernates, problem.

If so then MS-Windows still has the storage mounted. Writing to it will cause the file-system to become corrupted. Therefore MS-Windows has marked it as mounted, and Gnu/Linux is refusing to write to it (mounted it read-only).

If so, change settings in MS-Windows so that a shutdown does a shutdown.